Put blank values ​in a form when I change the name of an input
When I change the value of the name of the cruise, the value of places or ports is not changed and that can give me several problems, which is why I want the values ​​to be reset and blank when I change the name of the cruise, for example If I choose the Adventure cruise and the Alaska location, the ports of the Alaska location appear with the Adventure cruise, but if I change the cruise, all the ports appear instead of the Alaska ports appearing on that cruise, this is my code:
reservar.page.html:
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Reservar</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="reservaForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Nuestra Flota</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Crucero:" placeholder="Escoge un crucero" name="nombreCrucero"    formControlName="nombreCrucero" [compareWith]="compareFn" (ionChange)="onCruceroChange()">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let crucero of cruceros" [value]="crucero" type="text">{{ crucero.name }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Lugares para visitar</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Lugares para visitar:" placeholder="Que lugares quieres visitar" name="lugares" formControlName="lugares" [compareWith]="compareFn" (ionChange)="onLugarChange()">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let lugar of lugares" [value]="lugar" type="text">{{ lugar.name }}  </ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Escoge el puerto de salida</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Puerto de Salida:" placeholder="Escoge el puerto de salida" name="puertoSalida" formControlName="puertoSalida" [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let puerto of puertos" [value]="puerto" type="text">{{ puerto.name }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>   
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Cantidad de noches</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Número de noches:" placeholder="Escoge el número de noches" name="noches" formControlName="noches" type="number"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Cantidad de huéspedes</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Número de huéspedes:" placeholder="Escoge el número de huéspedes" name="huespedes" formControlName="huespedes" type="number" (ionInput)="calcularCamarotes()"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div style="text-align: center">Cada 4 huéspedes se te añade otro camarote</div>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Camarotes</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select label="Camarote:" placeholder="Escoge un camarote" name="nombreCamarote" formControlName="nombreCamarote" [compareWith]="compareFn">
        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let camarote of camarotes" [value]="camarote" type="text">{{ camarote.name }}</ion-select-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
    <div style="text-align: center">Puedes ver todos los camarotes en la sección "Camarotes" dentro de cada crucero</div>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Número de Camarotes</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input label="Número de camarotes:" placeholder="Escoge el número de camarotes" name="numeroCamarotes" formControlName="numeroCamarotes" [value]="reservaForm.value.numeroCamarotes" readonly></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="titulo" color="primary">
      <ion-title>Fecha de Inicio del Crucero</ion-title>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-datetime [min]="today" class="fecha" presentation="date" name="fechaInicio" formControlName="fechaInicio"></ion-datetime>
    <div class="boton">
      <ion-button type="submit" (click)="alertaReserva()" [disabled]="reservaForm.invalid">Reservar</ion-button>
    </div>
  </form>
</ion-content> 

reservar.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, Validators, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
import { MenuController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { ReservasService } from '../reservas.service';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reservar',
  templateUrl: './reservar.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reservar.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, RouterLink, IonicModule, ReactiveFormsModule ]
})
export class ReservarPage implements OnInit {

  today: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getDate();  
      
  }

  getDate() { const date = new Date(); this.today = date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2); console.log(this.today); }

  cruceros=[
    
  ]

  lugares = [
    
  ]

  puertos = [
    
  ]

  camarotes = [
    
  ]

  lugaresAdventure = [
    
  ]

  puertosAdventure = [
    
  ]

  lugaresAllure = [
    
  ]

  puertosAllure = [
    
  ]

  lugaresAnthem = [
    
  ]

  puertosAnthem = [
    
  ]

  lugaresBrilliance = [
    
  ]

  puertosBrilliance = [
    
  ]

  lugaresEnchantment = [
    
  ]

  puertosEnchantment = [
    
  ]

  lugaresExplorer = [
    
  ]

  puertosExplorer = [
    
  ]

  lugaresFreedom = [
    
  ]

  puertosFreedom = [
    
  ]

  lugaresGrandeur = [
    
  ]

  puertosGrandeur = [
    
  ]

  lugaresHarmony = [
   
  ]

  puertosHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  lugaresIcon = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosIcon = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresIndependence = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Europa' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]

  puertosIndependence = [
    { id: 5, name: 'Southampton, Inglaterra' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresJewel = [
    { id: 4, name: 'Canada y Nueva Inglaterra' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosJewel = [
    { id: 7, name: 'Boston, Massachusetts' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  lugaresLiberty = [
    { id: 4, name: 'Canada y Nueva Inglaterra' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Las Bermudas' }
  ]

  puertosLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresMariner = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosMariner = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  lugaresNavigator = [
    { id: 11, name: 'México' }
  ]

  puertosNavigator = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ] 

  lugaresOasis = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]
  
  puertosOasis = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresOdyssey = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Europa' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]

  puertosOdyssey = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  lugaresOvation = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Asia' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Australia y Nueva Zelanda' },
    { id: 11, name: 'México' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Pacífico Sur' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Transpacífico'}
  ]

  puertosOvation = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 23, name: 'Pekín (Beijing), China' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  lugaresQuantum = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Australia y Nueva Zelanda' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Hawái' },
    { id: 11, name: 'México' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Pacífico Sur' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Transpacífico'}
  ]

  puertosQuantum = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  lugaresRadiance = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Canal de Panamá' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Pacífico Noroeste' }
  ]

  puertosRadiance = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Seward, Alaska' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresRhapsody = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosRhapsody = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  lugaresSerenade = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alaska' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Canal de Panamá' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Pacífico Noroeste' }
  ]

  puertosSerenade = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Cartagena, Colombia' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Colón, Panamá' }
  ]

  lugaresSpectrum = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Asia' }
  ]

  puertosSpectrum = [
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 24, name: 'Shanghái (Baoshán), China' }
  ]

  lugaresStar = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' }
  ]

  puertosStar = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresSymphony = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosSymphony = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresUtopia = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosUtopia = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  lugaresVision = [
    { id: 4, name: 'Canada y Nueva Inglaterra' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Las Bermudas' }
  ]

  puertosVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  lugaresVoyager = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Australia y Nueva Zelanda' },
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 7, name: 'Europa' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Pacífico Sur' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Transatlántico' }
  ]

  puertosVoyager = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Atenas (El Pireo), Grecia'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Rávena (Venecia), Italia' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  lugaresWonder = [
    { id: 6, name: 'El Caribe' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Las Bahamas' }
  ]

  puertosWonder = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaAnthem = [
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' } 
  ]

  puertosAlaskaOvation = [
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Seward, Alaska' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaQuantum = [
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' } 
  ]

  puertosAlaskaRadiance = [
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Seward, Alaska' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaSerenade = [
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosAlaskaVoyager = [
    { id: 18, name: 'Seattle, Washington' } 
  ]

  puertosAsiaAnthem = [
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 26, name: 'Tokyo (Yokohama), Japón' }
  ]

  puertosAsiaOvation = [
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 23, name: 'Pekín (Beijing), China' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 26, name: 'Tokyo (Yokohama), Japón' }
  ]

  puertosAsiaSpectrum = [
    { id: 22, name: 'Hong Kong, China' },
    { id: 24, name: 'Shanghái (Baoshán), China' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaAnthem = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaOvation = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaQuantum = [
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosAustraliayNuevaZelandaVoyager = [
    { id: 25, name: 'Singapur, Singapur' },
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosCanadayNuevaInglaterraBrilliance = [
    { id: 7, name: 'Boston, Massachusetts' }
  ]

  puertosCanadayNuevaInglaterraLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosCanadayNuevaInglaterraVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosCanalPanamaRadiance = [
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCanalPanamaSerenade = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 17, name: 'San Diego, California' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeAdventure = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeAllure = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeBrilliance = [
    { id: 13, name: 'Nueva Orleans, Luisiana' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeEnchantment = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeExplorer = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeFreedom = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeGrandeur = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeIcon = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeIndependence = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeJewel = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeMariner = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeOasis = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeOdyssey = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeRadiance = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeRhapsody = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeSerenade = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Cartagena, Colombia' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Colón, Panamá' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeStar = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeSymphony = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeUtopia = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeVoyager = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosCaribeWonder = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaAllure = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaBrilliance = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Atenas (El Pireo), Grecia'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' }
  ] 

  puertosEuropaExplorer = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Rávena (Venecia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaIndependence = [
    { id: 5, name: 'Southampton, Inglaterra' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaOdyssey = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosEuropaVoyager = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Atenas (El Pireo), Grecia'},
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Rávena (Venecia), Italia' }
  ]

  puertosHawaiAnthem = [
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosHawaiQuantum = [
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasAdventure = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasAllure = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasBrilliance = [
    { id: 13, name: 'Nueva Orleans, Luisiana' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasEnchantment = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasExplorer = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasFreedom = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasGrandeur = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasIcon = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasIndependence = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasJewel = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasMariner = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasOasis = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasOdyssey = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasRadiance = [
    { id: 9, name: 'Fort Lauderdale, Florida' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasRhapsody = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 29, name: 'San Juan, Puerto Rico' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasSerenade = [
    { id: 20, name: 'Tampa, Florida' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Cartagena, Colombia' },
    { id: 28, name: 'Colón, Panamá' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasStar = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasSymphony = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasUtopia = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasVoyager = [
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBahamasWonder = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosBermudasLiberty = [
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosBermudasVision = [
    { id: 6, name: 'Baltimore, Maryland' }
  ]

  puertosMexicoNavigator = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ]

  puertosMexicoOvation = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ]

  puertosMexicoQuantum = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoNoroesteRadiance = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoNoroesteSerenade = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Puerto de cruceros de Vancouver, (Columbia Británica)' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurAnthem = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurOvation = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurQuantum = [
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosPacificoSurVoyager = [
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoAdventure = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoAllure = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoBrilliance = [
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoExplorer = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoHarmony = [
    { id: 10, name: 'Galveston, Texas' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoIndependence = [
    { id: 5, name: 'Southampton, Inglaterra' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Miami, Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoOdyssey = [
    { id: 3, name: 'Roma (Civitavecchia), Italia' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Cape Liberty (Nueva York), Nueva Jersey' }
  ]

  puertosTransatlanticoVoyager = [
    { id: 2, name: 'Barcelona, España' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Orlando (Puerto Cañaveral), Florida' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoAnthem = [
    { id: 14, name: 'Oahu (Honolulú), Hawái' },
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoOvation = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Los Ángeles, California' },
    { id: 26, name: 'Tokyo (Yokohama), Japón' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoQuantum = [
    { id: 31, name: 'Sídney, Australia' }
  ]

  puertosTranspacificoVoyager = [
    { id: 30, name: 'Brisbane, Australia' },
  ]

  onCruceroChange() {
    const cruceroSeleccionado = this.reservaForm.value.nombreCrucero;
    }
  }

  onLugarChange() {
    const lugarSeleccionado = this.reservaForm.value.lugares;
    const cruceroSeleccionado = this.reservaForm.value.nombreCrucero;
  }

  compareFn(o1, o2) {
    return o1 && o2 ? o1.id === o2.id : o1 === o2;
  }

  calcularCamarotes() {
    const huespedes = this.reservaForm.value.huespedes || 0;
    const numeroCamarotes = Math.ceil(Number(huespedes) / 4).toString();
    this.reservaForm.patchValue({ numeroCamarotes });
  }

  reservaForm = new FormGroup({
    fechaInicio: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    lugares: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    puertoSalida: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    noches: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    huespedes: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    nombreCamarote: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    numeroCamarotes: new FormControl("1", [Validators.required]),
    nombreCrucero: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
  })

  async onSubmit(){
    const datos = this.reservaForm.value
    await this.reservasService.guardarReserva(
      this.reservaForm.value.fechaInicio, 
      this.reservaForm.value.lugares, 
      this.reservaForm.value.puertoSalida,
      this.reservaForm.value.noches, 
      this.reservaForm.value.huespedes, 
      this.reservaForm.value.nombreCamarote, 
      this.reservaForm.value.numeroCamarotes, 
      this.reservaForm.value.nombreCrucero)
  }

  async alertaReserva() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: '¡Crucero Reservado Con Éxito!',
      message: 'Si quieres ver o cancelar tus reservas, lo puedes hacer desde tu perfil',
      buttons: ['Action'],
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
  
  constructor(public menu: MenuController, public reservasService: ReservasService, private alertController: AlertController) { 
    this.menuActive();
    this.lugares = this.lugares;
    this.puertos = this.puertos;
  }

  menuActive(){
    this.menu.enable(true, 'menu');
  }

}

I have been searching in the internet on how to do that but i didnt finde anything im new in ionic and I dont know a lot of things

so you need to clear several form values within the onCruceroChange method.
onCruceroChange() {
  this.reservaForm.get('lugares').reset();
  ...
  ...
  ...
}

or you can use: this.reservaForm.lugares = ''; 
